# sed output stagnate

Tags: scripting, directory, sed, grep

I have file names that map to directores. 
For example.

```
test ---> /to/path/test/program.c
```

I have a line that formats the output of sed into this currently

```
test0
test1
test3
```

All unique directories, I now need to add leading path and copy their respective c files. Is there a way to stagnate the output of sed while i carry about there processes.

Please and thank you.

Comment: It would help if you showed your input and how it's being processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send `sed` a SIGTSTP (such as is produced by pressing CTRL-Z) to pause it.  Send a SIGCONT (the `fg` command in Bash) to continue it.

Or you could just let it run, and do your processing afterwards...